# Match Last Byte of a Binary in a Guard

Tags: erlang

Is it possible to match the last byte in a binary using pattern matching. Something like:

```
<<Rest/binary, 45>> = BinaryToMatch
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, no (at least not in R14B01). You must also know the size of the binary.

```
Skip = byte_size(BinaryToMatch) - 1,
<<_:Skip/binary, 45>> = BinaryToMatch.
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can also do `45 = binary:last(Bin)`. Unfortunately this function is not a guard BIF.

Answer (score 2):

In erlang 19 (may be previous versions also support this, I don't test them) you can use this guard :

```
when binary_part(Key, {byte_size(Key), -1}) =:= BinMatchElement
```